# error: /usr/include/objc/objc-class.h: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone

I am currently using blocks in my UIButton category.  However I have come across this error which I cannot solve:

> error: /usr/include/objc/objc-class.h:
>   No such file or directory

This is the line of code that uses blocks:

```
FTButtonBlock block = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "buttonBlock");
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Change

```
#import <objc/objc-class.h>
```

to

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

From the blog entry: [error: objc/objc-class.h: No such file or directory](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/objcobjc-class-h)

Comment: @TheLearner :Still have same issue ?

Comment: Would be nice to post solution in question instead of link.  But thats just my preference.

Comment: tldr;

Then the solution is to change this import statement in SHK.m:


`#import <objc/objc-class.h>`

to:

`#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>`

or (on xcode 4.3.1):

`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: Thank you i just replaced this line: 
      #import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h> with this one: 
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: I had a problem with my Jenkins when I was trying build a version in XCode 7. After change from "#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>" to "#import <objc/runtime.h>", my build is back to normal. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replace current line with following line:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After xcode 4.6 this breaks again. I just fixed this like this :

```
cd /usr/include/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/objc .
```

Now it works like a charm